# Should there be different wrap and unwrap class types when creating custom hibernate type class?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-types

When I create a custom hibernate Type, such as

```
public class CustomHibernateType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Custom>
{
    public CustomHibernateType()
    {
        // Notice the JsonBinarySqlTypeDescriptor class from @vladmihalcea's hibernate types library
        super(JsonBinarySqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, CustomHibernateTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "CustomHibernateType";
    }
}
```

And create the Type Descriptor

```
    // only constructor for brevity, can include more if needed
    public CustomHibernateTypeDescriptor()
    {
        super(Custom.class, ImmutableMutabilityPlan.INSTANCE);
    }
```

I find that when I am saving and retrieving data in my custom hibernate type descriptor, the class type used is different. It is saved as a jackson `JsonNode`, which is expected as this is what is used in the `JsonBinarySqlTypeDescriptor` class, however when it is retrieved it is retrieved in the unwrap method as a PGobject (which has a simple string value).

Should I be expecting this, or should I be expecting JsonNode in both directions? I have no problems processing the PGobject, it just wasn't expected so I'm wondering if there is some config missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `wrap` method transforms the entity attribute type to the one that should be passed to the JDBC `PreparedStatement`.

The `unwrap` method transforms the object that was extracted from the JDBC `ResultSet` to the expected entity attribute type.